# Maven-Cargo integration test crashing due to spring version uncompatibility

Tags: spring, maven, cargo

I am developing an integration test involving a couple of webapps, but when compiling using maven, a linkageError is given due to version inconsistency between spring and spring context, even though I use the same version for both of them.
The pom.xml used is the following one:

....

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copies the war from repository and deploys on a jetty server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Container configuration -->
                <container>
                    <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </container>
                <!-- Configuration with the required deployable wars -->
                <configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>war context</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
    <!-- Don't wait, execute the tests after the container is started -->
                <wait>false</wait>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...

The error produced when prompting mvn verify:

```
2011-05-03 09:19:54.919:WARN::failed ContextHandlerCollection@10cafa1: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourceByPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/io/Resource;" the class loader (instance of org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext, and its superclass loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/core/io/Resource used in the signature
2011-05-03 09:19:54.919:WARN::failed HandlerCollection@1de7497: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourceByPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/io/Resource;" the class loader (instance of org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext, and its superclass loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/core/io/Resource used in the signature
2011-05-03 09:19:54.919:WARN::Error starting handlers
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourceByPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/io/Resource;" the class loader (instance of org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext, and its superclass loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/core/io/Resource used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:249)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.internal.JettyExecutorThread.run(JettyExecutorThread.java:69)
```

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the monolithic Spring-everything distribution. You don't need any other Spring Jar if you use this, it already contains everything. (And classpath clashes may result if you do)

Which is probably why the Spring guys have decided to no longer create a spring-all jar in 3.0.x

Comment: I've removed the spring-context dependency as you said, and the same error still appears. Is there a way to obtain which spring version uses the cargo plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed it from the cargo-maven2-plugin dependencies list as well?

By the way, I think you rather should delete the all-in-one spring dependency and leave spring-context, plus what you need (and only what you need).